# Reaching equilibrium in a blackbody and light-matter interaction

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, atomic-physics, thermal-radiation, quantum-optics

Suppose we have a metallic cavity maintained at a fixed temperature. Suppose we start with any distribution of radiation that is not in equilibrium with the container. Gradually, when the equilibrium is established, the radiation inside becomes a blackbody radiation at temperature T. Suppose initially the energy density corresponding to a frequency $\omega_1$ was greater than the equilibrium density at temperature T, and that corresponding to $\omega_2$ was lesser than the equilibrium density. How does the matter-radiation system, on its own, goes over to the Blackbody distribution? What tells the system to absorb extra photons of frequency $\omega_1$ and emit those at frequencies near $\omega_2$?

Is it anyhow relared to the Einstein coefficients? If yes, then how?

Is it possible to understand this in terms of interaction between the matter and quantized radiation?

Answer (score 2):

> How does the matter-radiation system, on its own, goes over to the Blackbody distribution?

Evolution towards equilibrium (in macroscopic sense) happens when the system matter + radiation is isolated, for example if a piece of matter is inside a cavity that slows down leakage of energy out of the system. For example, a piece of coal in a well reflecting metallic cavity.

There isn't any law in microscopic theory that would imply such system has to evolve to a "microstate" (EM field in the cavity) that corresponds to equilibrium macrostate (where Poynting energy density has the Planck frequency distribution).

But there are mathematical models (sets of equations) that show how a simplified system might approach equilibrium in time, such as the Einstein model of a molecule.

Let us consider a molecule that has 2 possible states - $g,e$ with energies $E_g$, $E_e$ and let the intensity of radiation at frequency $\omega$ be $\rho(\omega)$. Einstein introduced two processes:

- radiation-stimulated process, where the molecule changes its state due to presence of the EM radiation; expected average number of molecules that change their state per unit time is proportional to radiation intensity at frequency $\omega_{eg}=\frac{E_e-E_g}{\hbar}$ - let us denote this intensity as $I$;
- spontaneous process, where the molecule in the state $e$ changes into state $g$ on its own; expected average number of molecules that change their state this way per unit time is independent of the spectral density $\rho$ at any frequency.

Both processes are allowed to be happening at the same time.

Let the probability that the molecule is in state $e$ be $p_e$. Then the probability that the molecule is in state $g$ is $p_g = 1-p_e$. The above two processes allow $p_g$ to change in time and this can be described by the equation

$$
\frac{dp_e}{dt} = BI(p_g - p_e) - Ap_e.
$$

and when we use $p_g = 1-p_e$, this is

$$
\frac{dp_e}{dt} = BI - (A+2BI)p_e.
$$

If the intensity $I$ is constant in time, this equation has solution $p_e(t)$ that approaches the value

$$
p_{e,eq} = \frac{BI}{A+2BI}
$$

following exponential function of time.

This model describes a molecule interacting with prescribed EM radiation; if $I$ is that given by the Planck function, it only describes passage of molecules towards equilibrium, not of radiation.

However, each change of state of a molecule means the radiation gained or lost energy $E_e-E_g$. Since the radiation energy is also a functional of $\rho(\omega)$, this should have impact on the value of $I$. It should therefore be possible to extend the model so that $I$ is also time-dependent and solve the equations to get both $p_e(t)$ and $I(t)$, obtaining a picture of how the combined system approaches mutual equilibrium.

> What tells the system to absorb extra photons of frequency ω1ω1 and emit those at frequencies near ω2ω2?

Any system emits complicated radiation that has a range of frequencies, not just one. But considering the spectral function of the molecule to be a sharp peak, the above model implies that decreasing of radiation at frequency $\omega_1$ can happen if the population of molecules with this frequency has more molecules in $g$ state than is the equilibrium value for the current intensity $\rho(\omega_1)$.

> Is it anyhow related to the Einstein coefficients? If yes, then how?

Yes, $A$ is the Einstein coefficient of spontaneous emission, $B$ is the coefficient of stimulated emission/absorption.

> Is it possible to understand this in terms of interaction between the matter and quantized radiation?

Perhaps some understanding can be gained from the sketched model. It is a very simplistic and schematic one though, as it does not really involve basic laws of physics, but is based on lots of idealized assumptions.